# npm install -g @ionic/cli Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic6

I want to install ionic 6 on my system. I have installed multiple versions of npm on my system using nvm .

**nvm ls**

```
D:\<user_name>\Projects\Ionic-6>nvm ls

  * 16.14.2 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    16.14.0
    16.13.1
    14.17.3
    12.19.0
    10.0.0
    8.9.4
```

When I run `npm install -g @ionic/cli` I am getting below error:

```
D:\<user_name>\Projects\Ionic-6>npm install -g @ionic/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-01T11_25_55_752Z-debug-0.log
```

**Error Logs**

```
27 verbose stack C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmfund:1
27 verbose stack ../workspaces/libnpmfund
27 verbose stack ^
27 verbose stack
27 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
27 verbose stack     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
27 verbose stack     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
27 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
27 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
27 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
27 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
27 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
27 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
27 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.2\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\reify-output.js:16:38)
27 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
28 verbose cwd D:\
29 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
30 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@ionic/cli"
31 verbose node v16.14.2
32 verbose npm  v8.5.0
33 error Unexpected token '.'
34 verbose exit 1
35 timing npm Completed in 683ms
36 verbose code 1
37 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
37 error     C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-01T11_17_49_197Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Does this happen every time you install any package locally or globally or just for globally installing @ionic/cli?

Comment: Its weird that the command is running on version ```14.17.3``` and not on ```16.*.*```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by installing the latest version of [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)